# fetch facebook data php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

so i am trying to fetch some basic data from facebook and display it in plain text with this simple php and js code , it seems to work, but the problem is - if i change the url  of getJSON , it does add the new JSON to the file, but after 2sec delay it adds the previous fetched JSON data to the data.json file , it is really confusing for someone like me, anyone could give me some hints?  Thank you!

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
  file_put_contents('data.json', $_POST['data']);
}

$file = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'),true);
foreach ($file['data'] as $one) {
  if(strpos($one['message'], 'it') > -1) {
    echo '<p> ' . $one['from']['name'] . ' : ' . $one['message'] . '</p>';
  }
}

?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script> 
<script>
setInterval(function () { 
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/21785951839_10155105722796840/comments/?filter=toplevel&order=reverse_chronological&summary=true&access_token=mytoken";
    $.getJSON($url, function( data ) {
        $.post('index.php',{
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        },function(data) {

        });
    });
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `setInterval`?

Comment: script is checking for comments, but facebook limits returned comments count, so i am trying to fetch newest comments every 2 seconds, atleast thats what i think hehe

Comment: `if i change the url of getJSON` - how is it changed, in other words, what changes do you make to the url, don't care about the mechanism involved in changing the url because the code you posted has no way to change the url

Comment: the script is checking at some pictures comments, and i am changing to to another post comments , 21785951839_10155105722796840 this line to be exact

Comment: Why are you posting the requested data to the same page if you could just append it directly ? You are getting the data, posting it, writing a file, reading it back in, just to display it. Looks like you are over complicating things here. Also `setInterval` does not care if the request takes longer than 2 seconds, it will keep requesting event if the previous request has not finished executing the callback function.

Comment: I know it seems like a stupid mistakes, but it seems i can't figure it out, in any case someone would like a quick buck to make this work? I really don't have the time to teach myself enough js now :)